# How do I select the Current Project for Find & Replace

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-c++-2013

I don't see an option to tell VC++ what the current project is, so that I can search within a specific project within my solution, rather than the whole solution.

[image]

Is it something that happens as a side-effect of some other operation or can I somehow explicitly select which project is the current one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on a project in the Solution Explorer and select 'Set as Startup Project.' The 'Startup' project is the "current" project.

Comment: Jim Monte's answer is the correct one. Current project is the one highlighted not the startup project (in bold font) nor the one of the currently open file (as in WAQ's answer). You can test yourself.

Comment: @qwlice I don't know if it changed after 2019, but I'm currently running VS Professional 2022 version, and what you said is not true. WAQ's answer is the accurate one.

Answer (score 5):

currently opened file on which you opened the Find/Replace dialog belongs to a certain project. So that project is basically the "Current Project"

Comment: The same file can be in multiple projects. And you can open the find/replace dialog with no source files open at all, and it still chooses a project to use.

Comment: How can a file be in multiple Projects? The file that is opened in Visual Studio is from a particular location. At that location, there will be one file with that name.
When no source files open, in that case its a Visual studio bug, dialog should not open

Comment: A file can be in multiple projects if you add an existing file to another project. A project doesn't indicate a single directory, that's rather the point of searching by project rather than by directory in the first place, that it searches all the files in your project regardless where they are located.

Answer (score 2):

This question has a longer answer that it would seem. To make the Current Project selection, go to Solution Explorer and click on the desired project so that it is highlighted. It is not necessary to make the project your StartUp Project, but doing so will highlight the project as required to make it the Current Project for the search. You can make the project selection before or after opening the find/replace dialog. If you do not have a project selected (by selecting the solution), there is no current project and nothing gets searched.
However, there is at least one alternative. If the Property Manager is opened, a selection there will also set the current project. If both are opened, it appears that the last selection becomes the current project. This information is for VS2017, but probably it has been that way for many older versions since the Current Project search option has been around for a long time.